# Is there a way to satisfy mypy when adding methods (monkey patching or inheritance) to a class?

Tags: python, mypy

I'm working with some external code that has classes for items and groups of items. E.g., `Apple` and `BasketofApples`. I would like to add some methods to these and keep mypy happy.

This raises warnings (and arguably should) with monkey patching.

```
from typing import List


class Apple:
    pass


class BasketOfApples:
    def __init__(self, apples: List[Apple]) -> None:
        self.apples = apples


def _get_id_str(self: Apple) -> str:
    return str(id(self))


Apple.get_id_str = _get_id_str  # error: "Type[Apple]" has no attribute "get_id_str"

_ = Apple().get_id_str()  # error: "Apple" has no attribute "get_id_str"


def _get_id_strs(self: BasketOfApples) -> List[str]:
    return [x.get_id_str() for x in self.apples]  # error: "Apple" has no attribute "get_id_str"


BasketOfApples.get_id_strs = _get_id_strs  # error: "Type[BasketOfApples]" has no attribute "get_id_strs"

_ = BasketOfApples([Apple()]).get_id_strs()  # error: "BasketOfApples" has no attribute "get_id_strs"
```

And here are the warnings with a straightforward inheritance version:

```
from typing import List


class Apple:
    pass


class BasketOfApples:
    def __init__(self, apples: List[Apple]) -> None:
        self.apples = apples


class SonOfApple(Apple):
    def get_id_str(self) -> str:
        return str(id(self))


class SonOfBasketOfApples(BasketOfApples):
    def __init__(self, apples: List[SonOfApple]) -> None:
        super().__init__(apples)  # error: ... incompatible type "List[SonOfApple]"; expected "List[Apple]"

    def get_id_str(self) -> List[str]:
        return [x.get_id_str() for x in self.apples]  # error: "Apple" has no attribute "get_id_str"
```

Here is a no-warning version, but I've had to rewrite `SonOfBasketOfApples.__init__` without `super()`, which is just a taste of the mess I'd have to make by all-but rewriting `BasketOfApples`

```
from typing import List


class Apple:
    pass


class BasketOfApples:
    def __init__(self, apples: List[Apple]) -> None:
        self.apples = apples


class SonOfApple(Apple):
    def get_id_str(self) -> str:
        return str(id(self))


class SonOfBasketOfApples(BasketOfApples):
    def __init__(self, apples: List[SonOfApple]) -> None:
        self.apples = apples

    def get_id_strs(self) -> List[str]:
        return [x.get_id_str() for x in self.apples]
```

If I had access to the parent class (I don't), I could do this:

```
from typing import List, Generic, TypeVar


class Apple:
    pass


T = TypeVar("T", bound=Apple)


class BasketOfApples(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, apples: List[T]) -> None:
        self.apples = apples


class SonOfApple(Apple):
    def get_id_str(self) -> str:
        return str(id(self))


U = TypeVar("U", bound=SonOfApple)


class SonOfBasketOfApples(BasketOfApples[U]):
    def get_id_strs(self) -> List[str]:
        return [x.get_id_str() for x in self.apples]
```

Is there a saner way? Perhaps by hacking on `*.pyi` files?

Comment: You can use `Sequence` or `Iterable` instead of `list` for `BasketOfApples.__init__` and convert to `list` explicitly in constructor - list is invariant, while sequence (not mutable) is covariant, so `super().__init__` will be fine in `SonOfBasketOfApples`. Also you can make generic `Basket` class that will accept any type (probably with limits, you can use `TypeVar` bound to `Protocol` that defines `get_id_str`, for example).

Comment: Monkey patching is in general solution of last resort, there is no need to use it here.

Comment: @SUTerliakov Thank you, and, yes, if I could alter the parent Basket class, I could use generics. I've added an example of that to the top post. Unfortunately, I cannot alter the parent Apple or Basket classes.

Comment: This is probably a use-case for `cast`, but you'll have to decide if you are comfortable with this level of "lying" to `mypy` in order to reuse the given class in this way.

Comment: If you know that you will be calling a function that works with an `Apple`, why do you want it to make it a method on the object and then call it instead of calling it directly? The need would be more justified if you are actually monkey-patching something specific to each instance of `Apple`.